# Memory usage of php process

Tags: php, linux, memory

**SUMMARY**

---

Short recomendations (from more datailed informations, see answers)

To avoid memory leaks you can:

1. unset variables at once when they become useless
2. you can use **xdebug** for detailed report of memory consumption by functions and find memory leaks
3. you can set **memory_limit** (for example to 5Mb) to avoid dummy memory allocation

---

**QUESTION**

For what php can use memory, except libraries and variables?
I monitor memory, used by variables and its ~ 3Mb with this code:

```
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
        $cnt_vars = count($vars);
        $allsize = 0;
        for ($j = 0; $j < $cnt_vars; $j++) {

            try
            {
                $size = @serialize($$vars[$j]);
                $size = strlen($size);
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                $str = json_encode($$vars[$j]);
                $str = str_replace(array('{"','"}','":"','":'), '', $str);
                $size = strlen($str);
            }
            $vars[$j] = array(
                'size' => $size,
                'name' => $vars[$j]
            );
            $allsize += $size;
        }
```

and libraries takes ~ 18Mb (libcurl, etc.)
So total its 21 Mb,  but

> pmap -x (process)
>   shows, that total memory consumption is kB: 314028   RSS: 74704   Dirty: 59672

so, total real consumption is ~74Mb.
Also i see some large blocks with [anon] mapping in my pmap
For what PHP using this blocks?

php version: **5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14**
php extensions:

```
root@webdep:~# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: @Smar PHP Version => 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

Comment: You also should consider using Xdebug for profiling, it will give you function call level increasement of memory usage, and can produce callgrind files you can analyze with something useful like `kcachegrind`.

Comment: Do you execute this via Apache module or fastcgi/fpm or cli/cgi version? Different versions allocate and free memory differently. Keep in mind some memory is allocated but not used. Play arround with `memory_get_usage()` and `memory_get_usage(true)`, if you can't analyze with cachegrinder.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i using it via cli/cgi (command php <script>). About memory_get_usage - it gives me only size of variables (and equal to size, that i calculate with my code in question)

Comment: @Smar can you give me some links/examples of using this method?

Comment: @fiction: my comment grew a bit, so I added an answer.

Comment: @fiction: In `pmap -X <pid>`, what appears in the output ? I suppose `heap` is taking most of the consumed size ?

Comment: @ColinPitrat yes, heap is taking major part of memory

Comment: @fiction: you can have a look at this presentation for better understanding of php memory management: http://fr.slideshare.net/jpauli/understanding-php-memory and the associated article http://jpauli.github.io/2014/07/02/php-memory.html. You can try setting `report_memleaks=1` and disabling `USE_ZEND_ALLOC`. In addition to `memory_get_usage()`, you can have a look at `memory_get_peek_usage()` as a peek in memory usage can explain why zend would keep some memory allocated.

Comment: @ColinPitrat i saw this presentation, its very usefull, yes. But even memory_get_peek_usage() shows me much less memory usage, than heap size

Comment: @fiction Do you have a different behaviour when setting environment variable `USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0` ?

Comment: @ColinPitrat no, its the same

Comment: As one extra test you may want to do, is to test if the memory usage works as same with PHP 7 too. PHP 7 boasts to have some speed improvements, so it may alter memory usage too.

Comment: @Smar I spent some time with PHP 5.5, 5.6 and 7 regarding memory utilisation. Turns out PHP7 improves on CPU usages, Memory utilisation is still quite same. If you are concerned about higher memory usages try HHVM.

Comment: @Smar can you help me with one more question about memory?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767881/php-free-memory-after-unset

Comment: @UdaySawant maybe you can help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767881/php-free-memory-after-unset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOTE: this is not exactly an answer but information requested by the OP, but the comment field is too short for this... These are more of tools how to debug this kind of problems.

[Xdebug’s docs are pretty comprehensive](https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace), they should tell how to use it far better than I could by copying their docs to here. The script you gave is a bit fuzzy, so I did not do the trace myself, but it would give you line-by-line diffs of memory usage.

Basically set `xdebug.show_mem_delta` to `1` with Xdebug enabled to generate the function trace, which you can then open in a text editor to see what part exactly is the thing that leaks memory.

Then you can compare the initial (or middle position) total memory to see how much it differs from the real memory usage you are seeing.

```
TRACE START [2007-05-06 14:37:26]
    0.0003     114112  +114112   -> {main}() ../trace.php:0
```

Here the total memory would be the `114112`.

If the difference is really big, you may want to use something like [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec) to get the real memory usage in between all lines, and output that, and then you can compare that output to Xdebug’s memory output to see where the difference happens.

If the difference is from the very first line of the script, the culprit could be an extension of PHP. See `php -m` if there is any fishy extensions.

Comment: How can i check fishy extensions? I add list of php extensions to my question

Comment: You could disable them all, then enable them one at a time to test.

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that OPCache, since it’s Zend’s new speedup technology, so it could save something one does not expect. But what @quickshiftin said.

Comment: @Smar some days of debugging.. and i steel have a question... xdebug in the end of trace shows me 24735064 bytes in memory (~23.9 Mb)

BUT in pmap i can see 76 Mb used by process  (60Mb used by heap). So, i cannot imagine for what this 30 Mb is used for :(

And i detect, that process works and take ~23 Mb, and SUDDENLY it takes 76Mb

Comment: @fiction You got in the function trace the place where it jumps up in memory usage, so you know where the increase happens in code? Then you can put a pmap calls after that point (`shell_exec("..pmap..")`), redirect them to file to see if the memory ever decreases, and if the increase in PHP memory happens in same place. If it never decreases after increase, it’s most likely related to the memory allocation algorithm as Uday explain in the answer.

Comment: For more info, the memory allocator (at least in Java, but I assume in PHP too; I suspect PHP does it in bad way as PHP is useful in leaking memory in general...) sometimes pre-allocates bigger memory blocks it needs in advance, so it does not need to do allocation all the time. And Java used to never free that memory for the same reason.

Answer (score 6):

PHP is not same as C or CPP code that compiles to single binary. All your scripts are executed inside Zend Virtual Machine. And most of the memory is consumed by VM itself. That includes the memory used by loaded extensions the shared libraries (.so files) used by PHP process and any other shared resources.

I don't remember the exact source but somewhere I read that nearly 70% of total CPU cycles are consumed by PHP internals and only 30% get to your code (Please correct me if I am wrong here). This is not directly related with Memory consumption but should give an idea about how PHP works.

About anon blocks I found some details in another SO answer. The answer is about Java but same should apply to PHP as well.

> Anon blocks are "large" blocks allocated via malloc or mmap -- see the
>   manpages. As such, they have nothing to do with the Java heap (other
>   than the fact that the entire heap should be stored in just such a
>   block).

- Here's the actual link for SO answer
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483482/1012809
- Check this article for more details on anonymous memory pages (anon)
  https://techtalk.intersec.com/2013/07/memory-part-2-understanding-process-memory/
- Also check this Slide-share for more details on PHP memory management
  http://www.slideshare.net/jpauli/understanding-php-memory

I would recommend to disable some extensions. That should save you some unused memory.

Comment: So one interesting thing to try would be to reduce memory limit to something like 5 MB; if that fixes excessive memory allocation in OP’s case, I guess it’s just dummy allocation logic of PHP then (like in that case with Java, they’ve tried to fix that in newest Java versions AFAIK :-).

Comment: @Smar checking it now.. seems to be right, but i need to test it for day ot two, i will reply

Answer (score 2):

First of all make an array, to investigate memory it is taking

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = range(1, 100000);
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

one integer is `8 bytes` (on a `64 bit unix machine` and using the `long` type) and here `100000 integers`, so you obviously will need `800000 bytes`. That’s something like `0.76 MB`.

This array gives `14649024 bytes`. That’s `13.97 MB` - **eighteen times more than estimated**.

Here is a quick summary of the memory usage of the different components involved:

```
                             |  64 bit   | 32 bit
---------------------------------------------------
zval                         |  24 bytes | 16 bytes
+ cyclic GC info             |   8 bytes |  4 bytes
+ allocation header          |  16 bytes |  8 bytes
===================================================
zval (value) total           |  48 bytes | 28 bytes
===================================================
bucket                       |  72 bytes | 36 bytes
+ allocation header          |  16 bytes |  8 bytes
+ pointer                    |   8 bytes |  4 bytes
===================================================
bucket (array element) total |  96 bytes | 48 bytes
===================================================
total total                  | 144 bytes | 76 bytes
```

Again, for large, static arrays, if i call like:

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = new SplFixedArray(100000);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
$array[$i] = $i;
}
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

It will result `5600640 bytes`

That’s `56 bytes` per element and thus much less than the `144 bytes` per element a normal array uses. This is because a fixed array doesn’t need the bucket structure. So it only requires one `zval (48 bytes)` and one `pointer (8 bytes)` for each element, giving the observed `56 bytes`.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the numbers you see, you shouldn't combine them, this is just "tripling", you are seeing different sections (read-only, executable, writable) for libraries listed separately, your number is correct.