# PHP free memory after unset

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks

Its small code for test:

```
$strings = array('<big string here (2 Mb)');
$arr = array();

//--> memory usage here is 17.1Mb (checked by pmap)
echo memory_get_usage();//0.5Mb 
//(i know, that other 16.6Mb of memory used by process are php libraries)

for($i = 0; $i < 20; ++$i)
{
    $strings_local = array_merge($strings, array($i));
    $arr[$i] = $strings_local;
    unset($strings_local);
}

//--> memory usage here is 20.3Mb (checked by pmap)
echo memory_get_usage();//3.7Mb
//so, here its all ok, 17.1+3.2 = 20.3Mb

for($i = 0; $i < 20; ++$i)
{
    unset($arr[$i]);
}

//--> memory usage here is 20.3Mb (checked by pmap)
//BUT?? i UNSET this variables...
echo memory_get_usage();//0.5Mb
```

So, seems like php is not free memory, even if you `unset()` your variable. How can i free memory after unset?

Comment: I think PHP decides when to collect garbage on its own. There may be a way to force it to trigger a garbage collection but that still wont guarantee that what you've unset will be included in the collection. Do `gc_collect_cycles()` to force garbage collection (PHP 5.3 + )

Comment: @apokryfos how can i force garbage collection? I found this function -> `gc_collect_cycles`, but its for another purposes i think

Comment: I'd personally advocate to leave garbage collection alone and not deal with it. The point is, in any language that has a garbage collector, the language itself decides when it needs to run it. Garbage collecting is expensive. Also, take `pmap` usage stats with a grain of salt.

Comment: `gc_collect_cycles()` will enforce running of garbage collector (and hence collecting unused resources), but for the reasons @apokryfos mentioned, running it by hand is discouraged. It did have its used prior to PHP-5.3, as the GC did not do its job properly, but nowadays everything unused should be cleaned at least when you are running out of memory.

Comment: Again, for knowing how PHP sees the memory usage, use Xdebug’s function trace with memory delta to see if there is leak somewhere :) Even if PHP frees a resource, it may not free the memory to other processes, so outside inspection of memory may not give result of real memory usage, only what PHP has reserved to itself.

Comment: Also regarding loops in PHP, they finally fixed the loop behaviour (at least for `foreach`, so that *may* alter memory leaks related to them between PHP 5 and PHP 7. I have not tested it though.

Comment: @Smar so when my system memory will reach critical level, php will clean unused memory? Am i right?

Comment: @fiction: Rather, when a php process approaches its limit (the `memory_limit` in config), the GC will start to be more aggressive.

Comment: @fiction: Well, I’ll try to do some kind of answer. I don’t know internals of PHP really well, so my answer is not exactly the ”truth”, my knowledge is based to my experience and testing and general knowledge about how things with GC works. But best way to find out what exactly is happening is to do line-to-line debugging, as everything can change between versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has [garbage collector](http://php.net/gc) which takes care of the memory management for you, which affects to memory usage (of the process) in several different ways.

First, when inspecting memory usage of a process outside of the process, even if PHP sees some memory to be freed, it may not be released back to the OS for optimization purposes related to memory allocation. This is reduce overhead from continuous frees and allocs, that happen more easily with GC’d languages, as allocation procedure is not visible to the actual program.

For that reason, even if one calls `gc_collect_cycles()` by hand, the memory may not be freed to the OS at all, but rather reused for future allocations. This causes PHP to see smaller memory usage than the process in reality uses, due to some early big reservation which never gets to freed back to the OS.

Second, due to nature of garbage collection, the memory may not be immediately freed after marked unused by the program. Calling `gc_collect_cycles()` will make the memory freed immediately, but it should be seen unnecessary, and does not work if you have logical (or something in PHP leaks) memory leak in your script.

For knowing what is going on, doing line by line inspection (for example with Xdebug’s function trace) would give you better insight about how PHP (or rather, your program) sees the memory usage.

Combining that to line-by-line inspection from outside of the process (for example your `pmap` commands) would tell if the PHP actually is freeing any memory at any point after reserving it.