# Thread Management Memory Leak

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost, memory-leaks

I use the [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) in my C++ application.  I use a thread vector `std::vector <boost::thread> tvec {1000};` and an event queue `boost::lockfree::queue <int> events {1000};` to handle events.

My event dispatcher looks like this:

```
void my_class::event_dispatcher (void)
{
    INFO << "started";

    int event_element = 0;

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // 1. wait for an event
            for (;;)
            {
                if (events.pop (event_element)) break;  // returns true if the queue is not empty
                boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::milliseconds (250));      
            }

            // 2. handle event
            switch (event_element)
            {
                // 1-20 ...
                case 21:
                {
                    tvec.at(21).interrupt();
                    tvec.at(21) = boost::thread (boost::bind(&my_class::write_units_court_a, this));
                    break;
                }
                // 21-999...
                default:
                {
                    WARNING << "INVALID EVENT = " << event_element;
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        ERROR << "e.what() = " << e.what();
        return;
    }

    INFO << "ended";

    return;
}
```

My problem is that when I run `pmap -x PROGRAM_PID` it shows dozens of these lines:

```
00007f4063fd9000    8192      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f4063fd9000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f40647d9000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00007f40647d9000       0       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00007f40647da000    8192      16      16 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f40647da000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f4064fda000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00007f4064fda000       0       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00007f4064fdb000    8192      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f4064fdb000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f40657db000       4       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
00007f40657db000       0       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
```

which I assume to be a memory leak from my event dispatcher creating and interrupting multiple threads as the program runs.  I use boost logging in these threads and catch the interrupts in the threads properly; example:

```
void my_class::write_units_court_a (void)
{
    INFO << "started";

    try
    {
        // working code here ...
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        ERROR << "e.what() = " << e.what();     
        return;
    }
    catch (boost::thread_interrupted)
    {
        INFO << "interrupted";
        return;
    }

    INFO << "ended";

    return;
}
```

What is causing this seemingly thread memory leak?  Valgrind shows memory lost and I can see the program use more memory as it starts and ends threads.

Comment: Can you distill this into something self-contained? I'm not well versed in reading `pmap` so maybe you can elaborate a little bit on why you assume these are leaks

Comment: @sehe I assume they're leaks because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483482/4056146).  Tomorrow, I plan on trying `boost::shared_ptr <boost::thread> thr` instead of a thread vector and see if that helps .  I will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now use `boost::shared_ptr <boost::thread> thr_ev_21;` and

```
if (thr_ev_21.get()) thr_ev_21->interrupt();
thr_ev_21.reset(new boost::thread (boost::bind(&porter::write_units_court_a, this)));
```

Now my memory usage plateaus instead of constantly growing.  The thread object must not be destroyed with this line on the second pass:

```
tvec.at(21) = boost::thread (boost::bind(&my_class::write_units_court_a, this));
```